# Problems with css for my navigation bar

Tags: css

I am trying to make it so when a user hovers over  a link in my navigation bar the font colour changes to blue but I cant change it.
I have tried this:

```
#nav a:hover{
color: #1B8AD8;
background: none;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

But its still not working. Any help? JSfiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/0k6wnvs6/

Answer (score 0):

Try the below css

```
ul#nav li a:hover{
  color: #1B8AD8;
  background: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your rule is conflicting with another rule that are defined after it:

```
#nav li:hover a{ /* These create persistent hover states, meaning the top-most link stays 'hovered' even when your cursor has moved down the list. */
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #181818; /* <- conflict */
}
```

Either remove `color: #181818;`
or add `!important` flag to the original one:

```
#nav a:hover{
  color: #1B8AD8 !important;
  background: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

#### Edit:

you seem to be changing the css in your fiddle link while i'm updating my answer, just try to avoid conflict.